# Changing TextView to visible from one class to another class

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I am attempting to start a program with TextView being invisible and have it become visible again when certain things run in another class.

Here is the code for the TextView in the main cs:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TextView text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        text.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

    }
```

I am hoping to make the TextView turn Visible again in another class. I have tried using Intent but I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If by another class, you mean "a random Java class", then you can just pass the reference of the `TextView`. But if the other class is an `Activity`, then you cannot directly do that. If I understand correctly what you want, perhaps you want to use `startActivityForResult()`, then `onActivityResult()`. [Android Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: Hm, if you want to use intent then what i can suggest is just put a condition checker inside the OnCreate of the said "another class" (I assume it's another activity). Then if the condition is met just set the text.Visibility to visible.

Answer (score 0):

you can set visible param in layout xml to invisible

and set visibility to visible in your class if you need)